# I'm confused about a function outlined in a module of my bootcamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working with express.js and wondering how this function returns all the pertinent data about an animal. The query is searching an animal by name, it returns all of the info about the animal but I don't know how the function works.

```
function filterByQuery(query, animalsArray) {
    let filteredResults = animalsArray;
    if (query.diet) {
        filteredResults = filteredResults.filter(animal => animal.diet === query.diet);
    }
    if (query.species) {
        filteredResults = filteredResults.filter(animal => animal.species === query.species);
    }
    if (query.name) {
        filteredResults = filteredResults.filter(animal => animal.name === query.name)
    }
    return filteredResults;
}
```

Comment: read the documentation on filter.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @code because filter is not find

Comment: What do you not understand. If statement checks to see if a property exists in the query object. If it does it loops over the array and checks to see if the property matches the value. If it does it keeps the object in the array, if it does not it is ignored.

Comment: It returns everything in the given array that has the same diet, species, and name as the provided animal (but shouldn't that be the same animal?).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

So you have an array of animal objects/classes. You are trying to limit the array to the items that match. So the items you can match are diet, species, and name. Not all of them are required so you are doing a check to see what ones were specified.

The if statements are a truthy checks to see if the value exists in the query. So `if (query.diet) {` is saying is diet a truthy value? Yes, then we should apply this filter check.

The [Array `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) loops over every index in the array. If `true` is returned it keeps it. If `false` is returned it ignores it.

So when it does `animal.diet === query.diet` it returns the true or false and determines if the animal object has the same requirement as the query is asking for.

The final result of the function is a new array that has the animal objects that match the query parameters provided.